# What is the difference between using getDownloadUrl() vs. making the object public?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

Once someone shares the `getDownloadUrl()` link with the token parameter, anyone can access the object, the same as they would a public object. Is the only difference that that token can be revoked / changed? Or is it also easier to scrape / list objects in the bucket if they are public and don't require a token? I'm trying to understand the purpose of having a non expiring token.

Comment: To summarize my answer, take it as you have Netflix subscription but your friend can still use Netflix on your phone and not his :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to security rules by *"making public"* (or making the bucket public) then that just states who can request the download URL. If the bucket is private or the security rules don't allow anyone to access it, then they cannot request the download URL. However is by chance the manage to get the correct token and URL then they will be able to access that file.

To summarize, if someone who is not authorized to get a file, they would have to rely on someone who can request the donwload URL to access it (they cannot directly get one themselves).

If you make set permissions of your bucket to *"Public to internet"* from Google Cloud console, then if you visit root URL of the bucket you can see the contents:

[image]

By default, Firebase Storage's permission is set to "Not public" so no worries about that.

**Edit:**

If you allow `list` (requires `rules_version="2"`) then contents of your directory can be listed similar to this:

```
{
  "prefixes": [],
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Files/-Mf1kIafT6BnVnhgDQT2.pdf",
      "bucket": "[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Files/-Mf1pmCQMBNEdkQAnUjk.pdf",
      "bucket": "[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference: [Granular Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#granular_operations)

Comment: How does it work if the bucket is not public but a particular file is?

Comment: @Andrew just confirming: we are talking about Firebase Storage and it's security rules right? If any file/folder is public then any unauthenticated user can request download URL but they can't do the same for other private files. To get download URLs for private files user must pass the security rules.

Comment: If the bucket is not public but a particular object is, and the user doesn't know the object name, are they still able to scrape the bucket for the public objects? Will the bucket tell them the names of the public objects?

Comment: @Andrew I've updated my answer. Any directory which you've allowed to be accessed by anyone can be listed.