# Which Google Cloud services should I bundle to add online storage support to my desktop application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am writing an Electron app (built with Angular) and I am conducting research on how to add online cloud storage support to my desktop application?

The user shall be able...

1. to login into their account
2. to upload/download **their own** files to an online storage/drive.

The user shall basically be able to login into their account and upload and download **their own** files through the app.

### Question 1

Does a combination of `Firebase Authentication` + `Firestore Storage` sound like a proper solution for this requirement? Is there any limitation of these two services that might not work for this?

### Question 2

I have a related but different question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569757/how-can-i-use-firebase-storage-and-firebase-authentication-in-my-electron-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) is useful when it comes to user generated content. In fact, the description in the documentation says that,

> Cloud Storage for Firebase is built for app developers who need to store and serve user-generated content, such as photos or videos.

You can create a folders with users' UIDs as the key to restrict users to their own files:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{uid}/{files=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that security rules only prevent users from fetching the file's download URL   themselves. If a user (UID123) shares the link to one of their file to someone else (maybe unauthenticated), they still access view the file as they now have the URL with the access token. I've explained that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465361/13130697) as well.

These download URLs never expire unless the token is revoked.

[image]

If you want to prevent URLs being used for longer duration, you can generated [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#should-you-use). Anyone can still use these to view the files (if the user shares it) but you can set the expiration time on signed URLs.

Comment: Thats a fantastic explainer! Thanks a lot!