# How can I use Firebase Storage and Firebase Authentication in my Electron app?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, electron, google-cloud-storage

I am writing an Electron app (built with Angular) and I am conducting research on how to add online cloud storage support to my desktop application?

The user shall be able...

1. to login into their account
2. to upload/download **their own** files to an online storage/drive.

### Question 1

Which node (or Angular) modules can I use to access Firebase Authentication and Firebase Storage through my Electron app?

I found [electron-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-firebase), but the module seems to be in a non-working state.

### Question 2

I have a related but different question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569736/which-google-cloud-services-should-i-bundle-to-add-online-storage-support-to-my)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official library - [@angular/fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire), it is well documented and actively maintained by Firebase team. You can manage the authentication, uploading/or downloading in the client side.

Comment: I found that as well. Good to know I'm on the right track ;-) Thanks for the reply